# use a BroadcastReceiver to set an alarm?

Tags: android, alarm

Can you use a `BroadcastReceiver` to set an "alarm." Like not a notification, but an alarm?

So basically if I was to click a button it can set the alarm for 20 min from now or whatever my variable would be. I can figure out how to use it to set up a alarm from 20 mins from the current time, but I can do a toast notification that is as far as I got.

*Note that my var is 20 sec in my code*

```
public class SimpleSleepActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button setAlarm, setTimer;
    int hours = 1, alarmSec = 10;
    Toast mToast;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSetAlarm);
        setTimer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSetTimer);
        setTimer.setOnClickListener(mAlarmFromNow);
    }

    private OnClickListener mAlarmFromNow = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // When the alarm goes off, broadcast an Intent to the 
            // BroadcastReceiver. This is an Intent with an explicit class
            // name to have a receiver instantiated and called, and then 
            // create an IntentSender to have the intent executed as a broadcast.
            Intent intent = new Intent(SimpleSleepActivity.this,
                    AlarmFromNow.class);
            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    SimpleSleepActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

            // Finding the current time and setting and alarm for XX seconds
            // from that time
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, alarmSec);

            // Scheduling the alarm
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);

            if (mToast != null) {
                mToast.cancel();
            }
            mToast = Toast.makeText(SimpleSleepActivity.this,
                    //Show the user what they imputed
                    "The alarm will go off in " + alarmSec + " Seconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            mToast.show();
        }
    };
}
```

My other class is this:

```
public class AlarmFromNow extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Display a toast after alarmSec is counted
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.alarm_from_now, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want basically? need to set tone or what?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).